# How to solve a quadratic matrix equation in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve a quadratic equation in Python that is a matrix equation. I am looking for a matrix `Ax` that is 2x2 such that it will satisfy

> `M_1 Ax^2 - M_2 A_x - M_3 = 0`

where `M_1`, `M_2` and `M_3` are known 2x2 `numpy` arrays of constants and `Ax^2` is the matrix multiplication of `Ax` by itself.

My code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# Calibration
gamma = 0.36
beta = 0.98
b_bar = 0.1
psi = 0.001
g = 0.66
rho_x = 0.11
rho_z = 0.95
c_star = 1 + b_bar * np.exp(-g) * (1 - beta * np.exp(-g * (gamma - 1)))

# Matrices
M1 = np.array([[gamma, 0], [0,0]])
M2 = np.array([[gamma, psi * b_bar/(beta * np.exp(-gamma * g))],
              [c_star, b_bar * (beta * np.exp(-gamma * g) - psi * b_bar)]])
M3 = np.array([[0,0],
              [0, - b_bar * np.exp(-g)]])


fsolve(lambda Ax:  M1 @ Ax @ Ax - M2 @ Ax - M3, np.eye(2))
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 4 is different from 2)

Evaluating the function out of `fsolve` seems to work fine. I don't know what is going on. What am I missing? What is the best way to solve this system in Python? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried writing this out analytically?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649121/295281?

Comment: You need to pass in 1D vectors and sufficient data points to solve.

Answer (score 1):

*"You need to pass in 1D vectors and sufficient data points to solve."* – Mad Physicist

This would require some higher form of magic to do in a lambda expression. It is much more straightforward to implement such a wrapper in an explicit function definition

```
def fun(x):
    Ax = x.reshape([2,2]) 
    R = M1 @ Ax @ Ax - M2 @ Ax - M3
    return R.flatten() 

fsolve(fun, np.eye(2).flatten())
```

Comment: I would still maintain that this is the ugly way to do it given that an analytical solution exists.

Comment: But only in the case where everything is commutative. If `M1` is invertible, one can divide it out, so that `M1=I` remains. But note that `(A-M2/2)^2 = A^2 - (A*M2+M2*A)/2 + M2^2/4`, so that even then completing the square is not possible in the way of the commutative case.